# Get microphone sound level while recording in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, winmm, mcisendstring

I'm implementing a simple record, play application that can play and record a WAV file.
The requirements are as follows:

1) Windows 7, Visual studio 2010(or 2012), C#
2) Record, play Wav file with spec info: samplerate 22050, mono, bitspersample 16
3) Can display micro sound level while recording

With 1) and 2), I can use the lib (winmm.dll) and mciSendString() as follows

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]  
private static extern long mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);

// Open file to play
public void open(string file)
{
    string command = "open \"" + file + "\" type waveaudio  alias MyWav";
    mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
}

// Start playing
public void play()
{
    string command = "play MyWav";
    mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
}

// Stop playing
public void stop()
{
    string command = "stop MyWav";
    mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);

    command = "close MyWav";
    mciSendString(command, null, 0, 0);
}

// Start recording
public void record()
{
   string command = "open new Type waveaudio Alias MyRec";
    mciSendString(command, "", 0, 0);

    command = "set capture time format ms bitspersample 16 channels 1 samplespersec 22050 alignment 4";
    mciSendString(command, "", 0, 0);

    command = "record MyRec";
    mciSendString(command, "", 0, 0);
}

// Stop recording
public void stoprec()
{
    string fileName = @"""D:\Rec1.wav""";

    string command = "stop MyRec";
    mciSendString(command, "", 0, 0);

    command = @"save MyRec " + fileName;

    Debug.WriteLine(command);
    mciSendString(command, "", 0, 0);

    command = "close MyRec";
    mciSendString(command, "", 0, 0);
}
```

With 3), I also want to use mciSendString.  I found the following command (status):

```
string command = "status MyRec level ";
long mci_ret = mciSendString(command, "", 0, 0);
```

But I don't know to get volume from the above command, can anyone tell me the way?

Ref: the status command from mciSendString() is found in Microsoft doc:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
It says: 
level: Returns the current PCM audio sample value.

Comment: There are some great articales in codeproject [Vista Core Audio API Master Volume Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control?fid=410669&fr=126#xx0xx)

Comment: or [Change Master Volume in Visual C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/233484/Change-Master-Volume-in-Visual-Cplusplus)

Answer (score 0):

i monitor the levels by opening two devices, one for recording/playing(track1) and one to get the levels(waveLevel). The below is in foxpro.

```
* OPEN WAVE DEVICE FOR LEVEL READINGS 
= mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias waveLevel", '0&', 0, 0) 

* START RECORDING
= mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias track1", '0&', 0, 0)
```

then to get the level of track1 i use the waveLevel device

```
= mciSendString("status waveLevel level", @cBuff, LEN(cBuff) ,0)
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I end up using NAudio for my task. Reading up all the code and find out the good way to get it right. It's ok for both Windows 7 and 8(checked in some versions like Professional, Enterprise, Home Premium, .etc)